# Laravel Excel passing argument

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-excel

I'm trying to pass argument to filter the data I want to export to Excel.

This is my code :

```
class UnitExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection($proj_id)
    {
        return Unit::where('project_id', $proj_id);
    }
}


class UnitController extends Controller
{
    public function index($proj_id)
    {

        return view('dev-admin.projects.units.index', ['proj_id' => $proj_id]);

    }

    public function unitExcelExport($proj_id)
    {

        return Excel::download(new UnitExport($proj_id), 'Unit.xlsx');

    }
}
```

When try this it says i receive an error says:

> Declaration of
>   App\Http\Controllers\Developer\Admin\UnitExport::collection($proj_id)
>   must be compatible with
>   Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection::collection()

Comment: I believe the collection function in your UnitExport class should not have any parameter and the $proj_id should be used as the constructor argument not the collection function.
In your code, usage of "new UnitExport($proj_id)" seems not to be correct

Comment: you should pass $proj_id to the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass your argument directly to your collection function. Try this.

```
class UnitExport implements FromCollection
{
    protected $proj_id;

    public function __construct($proj_id)
    {
       $this->proj_id = $proj_id;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return Unit::where('project_id', $this->proj_id)->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi i receive this error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()"

Comment: at this line return Excel::download(new UnitExport($proj_id), 'Unit.xlsx');

Comment: nvm I just need to add get() when query, this works thanks